# nested html list to json

Tags: html, json, nested-sets

```
    [
 {
   "tree_id": 6,
   "fields" : ["id","lft", "rgt"], // tree_id is stripped if requested via fields because redundant
   "values" :
       [1,1,4,[
           [2,2,3,[]]
       ]]
 }
 // more could follow ...
]
```

above is the json code that Bobab uses to export/import nested sets. 
[Baobab nested set json export/import format](http://www.sideralis.org/baobab/api.html#Baobab.export)

How can i parse a nested html list to yield json like above?

I am trying to manipulate nested lists using drag and drop 
[Nestable list](http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/)

It has 2 functions that kind of do what i want to achieve, but my head keeps twisting around it.

```
        toHierarchy: function(options) {

        var o = $.extend({}, this.options, options),
            sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0,
            ret = [];

        $(this.element).children(o.items).each(function () {
            var level = _recursiveItems(this);
            ret.push(level);
        });
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
        return ret;

        function _recursiveItems(item) {
            var id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
            if (id) {
                var currentItem = {"id" : id[2]};
                if ($(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).length > 0) {
                    currentItem.children = [];
                    $(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function() {
                        var level = _recursiveItems(this);
                        currentItem.children.push(level);
                    });
                }
                return currentItem;
            }
        }
    },



    toArray: function(options) {

        var o = $.extend({}, this.options, options),
            sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0,
            ret = [],
            left = 2;

        ret.push({
            "item_id": o.rootID,
            "parent_id": 'none',
            "depth": sDepth,
            "left": '1',
            "right": ($(o.items, this.element).length + 1) * 2
        });

        $(this.element).children(o.items).each(function () {
            left = _recursiveArray(this, sDepth + 1, left);
        });

        ret = ret.sort(function(a,b){ return (a.left - b.left); });
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
        return ret;

        function _recursiveArray(item, depth, left) {

            var right = left + 1,
                id,
                pid;

            if ($(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).length > 0) {
                depth ++;
                $(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function () {
                    right = _recursiveArray($(this), depth, right);
                });
                depth --;
            }

            id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || 'id')).match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));

            if (depth === sDepth + 1) {
                pid = o.rootID;
            } else {
                var parentItem = ($(item).parent(o.listType)
                                         .parent(o.items)
                                         .attr(o.attribute || 'id'))
                                         .match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
                pid = parentItem[2];
            }

            if (id) {
                    ret.push({"item_id": id[2], "parent_id": pid, "depth": depth, "left": left, "right": right});
            }

            left = right + 1;
            return left;
        }

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to insert that data on the database using the Baobab library then you do not need to create the JSON code with the left/right indexes yourself, which can be fairly complicated to do.

Just send to the server tree structured data and on server side iterate over it adding the objects to the database.

You could create a generic tree structure with something like this (using jQuery to have a shorter example):

```
function genTree(domNode){
  var parentObj = {
    data : { /* filled with data found in domNode, e.g. the baobab node id */ },
    children: []
  };

  $(domNode).find('> li, > ul > li').each(function(){
    parentObj.children.push(genTree(this));
  });

  return parentObj;
}
```

Then when you'll travel the structure you will use the Baobab API to add the nodes to your database (at that point you can export it to JSON if you really need it)

Comment: I am trying to manipulate nested lists using drag and drop http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/